# Delegate/Outlet in NSTableCellView subview is null

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I have a `NSTableView` that lists a number of `NSTableCellView` with a couple of subviews. Everything is set up with Cocoa bindings and works just as it's supposed to, until I tried to delegate from one of the subviews to the File's Owner. The delegating subview has an `IBOutlet` and it's connected to the File's Owner in IB, but when the subviews receives a mouseUp method call the delegate is null.

Any idea of why? Is this because I'm using bindings and Interface Builder? I've done similar things before when setting up up the `NSTableView` programmatically, setting the delegate like this: `tableRowView.aSubView.delegate = self`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this in my warnings: `Outlet 'delegate' of 'MySubview' is connected to 'File's Owner,' an invalid destination (Objects inside view based table views may only be connected to the table view's delegate.)`. Setting the File's Owner as my table views delegate solved my problem.